# How to select the first row data of the database from the data table using C#?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio

How can I select the first row of the data in the datatable? And display the content on a labelbox, and radiobuttons?

```
OleDbDataAdapter dAdap = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
dAdap.Fill(dTable);
foreach(DataRow row in dTable.Rows)
{
    question = row["QUESTION"].ToString();
    c1 = row["C1"].ToString();
    c2 = row["C2"].ToString();
    c3 = row["C3"].ToString();
    c4 = row["C4"].ToString();
    ans = row["ANSWER"].ToString(); 
}
lblQuest.Text = question;
btnA.Text = c1;
btnB.Text = c2;
btnC.Text = c3;
btnD.Text = c4;
```

I tried this code, but it only displays the last row. Also when I try to rerun the query. It didn't refresh/replace/overwrite the values, it only displays the last row of the first query.

edit:

```
i = 0;
x = 0;
lblQuest.Text = dTable.Rows[i].Field<string>(x);
btnA.Text = dTable.Rows[i].Field<string>(x + 1);
btnB.Text = dTable.Rows[i].Field<string>(x + 2);
btnC.Text = dTable.Rows[i].Field<string>(x + 3);
btnD.Text = dTable.Rows[i].Field<string>(x + 4);
```

Comment: Because in each iteration you are overwriting the previous value in your variables.

Comment: Do you actually *understand* what that code does? I think that will be key to a solution ...

Comment: sorry, can you suggest how to improve it? change the foreach statement or change to another loop?

@Fildor, can you correct me. in the foreach im assigning the the contents from the table to its respective variable. then im lost. sorry.

Comment: That's correct. But as already said, you overwrite in each iteration. So to get the first row, use no loop at all. If you want to have a "next" button as stated by you in comments you'll probably save the DT as class field and use some kind of binding.

Comment: @Fildor

i tried using this. i edited my post. thanks for pointing out not to use loop. ill study and improve the code. as of now that code will be my baseline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that your variables are being overwritten with each loop. Once the loop gets through the whole DataTable it ends with the last row and only displays that.

To get the functionality you want you will need to store the DataTable as a property instead of a local variable.

One approach from there is to keep track of the row you are currently viewing. Then when the next button is clicked just ++ that current number and reassign the values.

```
class YourClass
{
    private DataTable dt { get; set; }
    private int CurrentRow { get; set; }

    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter dAdap = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
        dt = new DataTable();
        dAdap.Fill(dt);
        CurrentRow = 0;
        AssignToRow();
    }

    private void AssignToRow()
    {
        var row = dt.Rows[CurrentRow];
        lblQuest.Text = row["QUESTION"].ToString();
        btnA.Text = row["C1"].ToString();
        btnB.Text = row["C2"].ToString();
        btnC.Text = row["C3"].ToString();
        btnD.Text = row["C4"].ToString();
    }

    private void NextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentRow++;
        AssignToRow();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah cause the variable will get overridden on every iteration and you will end up having the values for only last iteration

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select only first row values use `dTable[0][ColumnIndex]`

To load next row on button click do:

```
int currentRow = 0;
DataTable myDt;

private void LoadNextRow()
{
    currentRow++;
    myLabel.Text = myDt[currentRow]["MyColumn"].ToString();
}

private void OnButtonClick(....)
{
    LoadNextRow();
}
```

Comment: actually, i just want to start from the first row. then when i click next. it will show the second, and so on.

Comment: So you have button `next` and when you press it, it needs to load new values from next row?

Comment: yes. but i can't construct the syntax for that button since im stuck with this.

Comment: While this will probably work for this simple example, OP may be better off reading himself into "Data Binding" ...

Comment: Good documentation for DataTables and all for that is this [Link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6178/A-Practical-Guide-to-NET-DataTables-DataSets-and-D)